# Storing values in a struct array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have a sqlite database having full of songs and lyrics and I am trying to retrieve and store them in an array.  I have declared the array like below

```
struct KArray {
let SongTitle: String
let SongLyrics: String
let ESongTitle: String


func match(string:String) -> Bool {
    let lowerCaseKeyword = string.lowercaseString
    return SongTitle.lowercaseString.containsString(lowerCaseKeyword) || ESongTitle.containsString(lowerCaseKeyword)

    }
}


var keerthanaiArray = [KArray]()
```

and I am populating the array with the values read from the sqlite table like below

```
keerthanaiArray = [KArray(SongTitle : songTitleT!, SongLyrics : songLyricsT!,
                    ESongTitle : EsongTitleT!)]
```

But it's not getting stored as array, only the last entry is stored.  Please assist

Comment: Replace `keerthanaiArray = [KArray(...)]` by `keerthanaiArray.append(KArray(...))`. – But your names are misleading, `KArray` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

As @Martin mentioned, your `KArray` is a struct, not an array.

If you want `keerthanaiArray` to be an array with the values of your `KArray` struct, try this:

```
var song: KArray  // initialize struct here
var keerthanaiArray = [String]()
keerthanaiArray = [song.SongTitle, song.SongLyrics, song.ESongTitle]
```

Comment: I am sorry I didnt quiet understand when you mentioned 'initialize struct here'.  Could you please elaborate

Comment: You have to set values for the properties in your struct (i.e. SongTitle, SongLyrics, ESongTitle) in order for it to be useful. See the **Initializers** section on [this site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Comment: I'd recommend creating a custom initializer inside the struct that you can call from outside the struct.

Comment: I have included the below init within the Struct                               ~                       init(SongTitle: String, SongLyrics:String, ESongTitle: String) {
        self.SongTitle =  SongTitle
        self.SongLyrics = SongLyrics
        self.ESongTitle = ESongTitle
    }
    ~

Comment: But this doesn't work.. Not sure how I can populate keerthanaiArray with my table values songTitleT, songLyricsT,EsongTitleT (these are retrieved from sqlite table).  I need to use these values to construct the array

Comment: To construct which array? KArray or keerthanaiArray? Your question is confusing because it seems that you have no need for the struct.